# Clone a Composer configuration using Composer commands

Tags: composer-php

I have a project which has had Composer added to it. I recently discovered that the Production packages were updated a long time ago without committing the `composer.json` or `composer.lock` files to Git.

I have set up a brand-new development and testing environment from the latest in our Git, which unbeknownst to me, was using the wrong versions of some packages.

I've manually `require`d all the exact versions to match Production, and the `composer.lock` files are now almost, but not entirely, identical.

I had to copy the exact Composer version (halfway between beta1 and beta2) to get this far.

These are the changes I now want to make in diff format where (-) is Dev/Test and (+) is Production:

```
    {
        "name": "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle.git",
            "reference": "c0a2f5d069e56e2ac7a42719dfda63fd996a39ed"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
-           "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/zipball/d78e19f96b54aed55aceedcdddd0fdc994b1010b",
+           "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/zipball/c0a2f5d069e56e2ac7a42719dfda63fd996a39ed",
            "reference": "c0a2f5d069e56e2ac7a42719dfda63fd996a39ed",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.0",
            "doctrine/migrations": "^1.1",
            "php": ">=5.4.0",
-           "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.7|~3.3|~4.0"
+           "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.3|~3.0"
        },
+       "require-dev": {
+           "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8"
+       },
        "type": "symfony-bundle",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "1.1-dev"
            }
        },
...
    {
        "name": "doctrine/migrations",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/doctrine/migrations.git",
            "reference": "0d0ff5da10c5d30846da32060bd9e357abf70a05"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
-           "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/migrations/zipball/488fb6994839eb1e10b823532888ea0ff9d19846",
+           "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/migrations/zipball/0d0ff5da10c5d30846da32060bd9e357abf70a05",
            "reference": "0d0ff5da10c5d30846da32060bd9e357abf70a05",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "doctrine/dbal": "~2.2",
            "ocramius/proxy-manager": "^1.0|^2.0",
            "php": "^5.5|^7.0",
            "symfony/console": "~2.3|~3.0",
            "symfony/yaml": "~2.3|~3.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "doctrine/coding-standard": "dev-master",
            "doctrine/orm": "2.*",
            "jdorn/sql-formatter": "~1.1",
            "johnkary/phpunit-speedtrap": "~1.0@dev",
            "mockery/mockery": "^0.9.4",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.7",
            "satooshi/php-coveralls": "0.6.*"
        },
        "suggest": {
            "jdorn/sql-formatter": "Allows to generate formatted SQL with the diff command."
        },
        "bin": [
            "bin/doctrine-migrations"
        ],
        "type": "library",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
-               "dev-master": "v1.4.x-dev"
+               "dev-master": "v1.5.x-dev"
            }
        },
...
    {
        "name": "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle.git",
            "reference": "ead0b44c6a9a96c1817710cd854665ee755afe04"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
-           "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/zipball/f7c2541008525bb621a0bd492e1d83a6d2b48adf",
+           "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/zipball/ead0b44c6a9a96c1817710cd854665ee755afe04",
            "reference": "ead0b44c6a9a96c1817710cd854665ee755afe04",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "knplabs/knp-snappy": "~0.1",
            "php": ">=5.3.2",
            "symfony/finder": "~2.3|~3.0",
            "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.3|~3.0",
            "symfony/validator": "~2.3|~3.0"
        },
        "type": "symfony-bundle",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "1.5.x-dev"
            }
        },
```

What Composer commands can I use to get the two files to match exactly, thereby presumably having exactly the same packages in all environments? If certain lines make no difference (such as the exact Git URL), I'm happy to copy the lines manually.

Answer (score 0):

To match the exact version of a package which is used in the composer.lock, you could require the exact commit hash in the composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-master#2eb0c0978d290a1c45346a1955188929cb4e5db7"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've done that via `composer require <release>#<hash>`. I've made a bit of a mess of `composer.json`, but since that didn't change on Production, I'll just revert it before committing to Git.